# How to parse a dynamic ASP page

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I need to write a script that can navigate through this ASP page:

http://fcms.concordia.ca/fcms/asc002_stud_all.aspx

and make a search so that I can parse the results (that are loaded dynamically).
I would prefer to be able to do it in PHP; is it possible?

Comment: Once an asp page is rendered, it's just html and javascript.  No need to specify an asp page.

Comment: just google it "html parser php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just figure out the parameters, make a post and parse the result.

The submit-button fires off the asp.net __doPostback call which simply adds view state and event arguments to the form data and submits the form.

Essentially this means you can do the same: make a get, parse the document and issue a postback with these arguments in the post body and with relevant headers.

You could play around with curl & inspect the post arguments + headers in firebug or chromes inspector.

Terminal curl-call (example) :

```
curl --data "ctl00$PageBody$ddlTimeBtw=&ctl00$PageBody$ddlCampus=" "http://fcms.concordia.ca/fcms/asc002_stud_all.aspx"
```

Here's a library that can abstract the post for you [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).